# Warning message: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 31 rows

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to fit multiple regression model on a training dataset. When i use the model to predict output on test data. it is showing 'Warning message: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 31 rows'. I am attaching the part of code I am working on

```
data_train<-data_train[-17,]
test_data<-data_train[17,]
mymodel<-lm(data_train$TW~data_train$CD+data_train$FR+data_train$SS+data_train$CL+data_train$P, data_train)
a<-predict(mymodel, test_data)
```

Comment: Build your model like this `mymodel<-lm(TW~CD+FR+SS+CL+P, data=data_train)
`

Comment: Generally don't use `$` inside of formulas (`~`).